# order initializiation static parameter

Tags: c#, initialization, declaration, specifications

Is there any specification for the order in which static readonly parameters are initialized?

In the following example, can one be sure, the array is always created with a length of 6?

```
public class Foo {
    private static readonly int MAX_STACKSIZE = 6; 
    private static readonly int[] m_stack = new int[MAX_STACKSIZE]; 
}
```

Or is there any chance of m_stack being initialized *before* MAX_STACKSIZE ?

@Edit: changed *const* to *static readonly*

Comment: Have you try to compile this?

Comment: The order isn't the problem. As long as you have no cycles it will work. But you can't have a non null constant of `int[]`. You need to make it a static readonly field.

Comment: Nope. should have checked it before... ;) thanks

Comment: I'd define `MAX_STACKSIZE` as const and only m_stack as static readonly field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was written when the sample code contained "const" instead of "static readonly". It's not valid for the current version of the question - I may write another answer to deal with that at some point, but I don't have time right now.

That won't be valid C# anyway, as you can't set a `const int[]` to anything other than null.

However, in the more general case, section 10.4 of the C# spec applies:

> Constants are permitted to depend on other constants within the same program as long as the dependencies are not of a circular nature. The compiler automatically arranges to evaluate the constant declarations in the appropriate order.

It then gives the following example:

```
class A
{
    public const int X = B.Z + 1;
    public const int Y = 10;
}

class B
{
    public const int Z = A.Y + 1;
}
```

and says...

> the compiler first evaluates A.Y, then evaluates B.Z, and finally evaluates A.X, producing the values 10, 11 and 12 in that order.

Comment: "That won't be valid C# anyway, as you can't set a const int[] to anything other than null." -> the question was first (incorrect) given with local const parameters. edited them to static readonly. Just for the archive...

Comment: @user492238: That's completely invalidated the question though - as static readonly fields aren't constants. The bit of the C# spec that I quoted no longer applies!